# Check if location is known

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xamarin.ios

I see many questions and answers about whether location is permitted by the user etc. This is *not* my question.

I want to know whether location is **known** to the device. Even if location is permitted and the GPS is on, the device might not know its location because it's in a tunnel, for example.

How do I check if location is known?

Comment: The device pretty much always knows *a* location, even if it was just the last GPS signal received before it went into a tunnel You can only really check the `horizontalAccuracy` property of the location; this will give an indication

Answer (score 0):

In iOS , **CLLocation** has a property **[horizontalAccuracy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423599-horizontalaccuracy?language=objc)** .

And there is a **Discussion** in official document :

> The location’s latitude and longitude identify the center of the circle, and this value indicates the radius of that circle. A negative value indicates that the latitude and longitude are invalid.

Therefore if its value is negative , then it means that location unknown.

```
CLLocation location = new CLLocation();
if( location.HorizontalAccuracy > 0)
{
    // it works
}
else
{
    //unknown location
}
```